# How to get value of a button type button with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I use  instead of 
I simply wish to get the value/content of the selected/active button, with jQuery, on click button and onload page.

These are my buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="green test">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="green active test">Button 2</button>
```

I know I must to use $(".test:button") selector, but I don't know how to get the button content

Comment: Hi guys,
the problem is I have more button with the same class and I need to know the value of SELECTED button.
In my example I have the 'Button 2' with class = "green **active** test".
Is there a way to know the value of a selected button OR a button which contains "active" attribute in class?

Comment: check my edit on how to get the button containing active

Comment: Hi @Anton,
the problem is that I have more buttons with the same "active" class, e.g.:

<button class="green active">Button 1</button>
<button class="green">Button 2</button>
<button class="red active">Button 3</button>
<button class="red">Button 4</button>

So, I cannot only use .active selector

Comment: So you want to select a button which has green or red and active?

Comment: yes! I wish to select more classes: e.g.: 'green' AND 'active'

Comment: I'll update my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.text()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    alert($('.test[type="button"]').text());

    $('.test[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
         alert($(this).text());
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TzvW6/)

**Edit**

```
var text = $('button.active').text();
```

**Edit**

```
var redsText = $('button.red.active').text();
var greensText = $('button.green.active').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').text();
```

or

```
$('button').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $('button.test').click(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1446/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<head> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button type="button" class="green test">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="green active test">Button2</button>
<script>
$(function(){
$(".green").click(function(){
$(this).addClass('active');

    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active")
alert($(this).text());
})
 })
</script>
```